# OAuth2 CallBack Google Custom Tabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am developing an Android Application that uses the FitBit API to retrieve a User's data. These are then used further in the application. In order to make this work, OAuth2 is used for authorization. First step is to get the user's consent to use data in a particular scope.

In order to make this work, I use Google Custom Tabs as prescribed by FitBit. The url works in a web browser, when I test it on an Android device it works too, directs me to the User Consent Page. When I hit the "Agree" button, I do not get redirected to the Application. Instead, I end up on the callback_url page with the Authorization Code.. Still I get nothing back through "System.in.println()". HOW DO I END UP BACK IN MY APPLICATION WITH THE AUTHORIZATION CODE IN SYSTEM.IN?

The following is the page I end up on..

[image]

I use a redirect_url for Development purposes, "http://locallhost.com/", to allow me to test in development. This is set up in the Manifest as an Intent Filter (see below), the Application settings of my Application at Fitbit API EndPoint.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final CustomTabsIntent intent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
    final String url = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize/myApplicationParameters";
    intent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));

System.out.println(in.hasNextLine());
```

The Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:host="locallhost.com/"
      android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback URL - API Call OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242901/callback-url-api-call-oauth2)

Comment: the dupilicate link-> that question is removed, and im still having this issue

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using callback_uri "niels://fitbitcallback". It was confusing to the Android Studio to use http:// or https://. This did not work for me. On top of that I used an additional activity to redirect the user to. Also adapted the Android Manifest accordingly.